# Shopware REST API getting value of taxid, not the id

Tags: rest, shopware

i want to import articles from a shopware system with the Rest-API (http://en.community.shopware.com/_detail_1898.html?_ga=1.8143281.202311237.1474979143) works good.

Is it possible, to get the value of the tax? I only get the id (taxid), but I need the value (7% / 19% or something else). I want to avoid some additonal database-queries, a REST-Api-Call would be perfect.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible solutions.

1. Hook into the API and join the tax info. Output the data nested.
2. Make a second call to the Tax-Endpoint.

https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/models/#tax